# Loading fixtures in django fails. 0 value for autofields

Tags: mysql, django, json, fixtures

Im trying to load data from a django-fixture which I created with the dumpdata command

```
manage.py dumpdata --format=json MyApp > MyApp/fixtures/test_data.json
```

I want to use this as initial data for my Unit-Tests like this

```
class SomeTest(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_data.json']
```

But I get an error when running my tests

> ValueError: Problem installing fixture 
>   The database backend does not accept 0 as a value for AutoField.

I'm running django version 1.5 and mysql version 5.2.40. Googling didn't really help so far. Any Ideas? Appreciate the help!  :D

Comment: Take a look here can maybe depend to it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero